# Matching dynamically added events (as attributes) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jquery-selectors

How can I match all elements that have a specific attribute that is added at run time?

For example, the code:

```
$('[onkeydown]')
```

will successfully match:

```
<div onkeydown="foo();">
```

but won't match the following div:

```
<div id="mydiv">
// ....
<script type="text/javascript">
var element = document.getElementById('mydiv');
element.onkeydown = foo;
</script>
```

Note: the ID attribute is used as an example. I do not know the ID's attribute values of all the elements I want to match, so please provide a solution which matches all elements that have an attribute specified.

To clarify, in the second example, the following code correctly returns the function that is used:

```
$('#mydiv').attr('onkeydown') // == foo
```

Note: if I do the same thing above, but instead of using an event (`onkeydown`), I use a different attribute which isn't an event (e.g. `title`), it will successfully match the dynamically added attributes. Thus, it seems like it is only a problem with events.

Comment: Is this for event handlers, or running plugins/modifying the elements?

Comment: @Nick: I'm not sure I understand the question fully, but after I have the matched elements, I want to remove it with code such as `myElements.removeAttr('onkeydown')`.

Comment: @Senseful - When are the events added? Something *else* is attaching an `onkeydown` handler and you want to remove it, correct?

Comment: @Nick: on load... yes something else is attaching them... I can't prevent this behavior. Hence I want to match all of the elements after it has been added.

Comment: @Senseful - Does this other function have a callback, etc, anything you can attach onto, to run when it's complete?

Comment: @Nick: no, there are no such callbacks. I'm getting the feeling that there's no easy way to do this with jQuery...

Comment: @Senseful does it work with an attribute that is *not* an event handler? Just to clarify what the problem is

Comment: @Senseful and you are 100% sure the timing is correct? i.e. the JS assigning the property is running when the element already existis, and your jQuery selector after that?

Comment: @Pekka: yes I am, since I am running it well after the page is loaded using the javascript console for now.

Comment: @Senseful hmm. Does it work with an attribute like `title`? Event handlers might get special treatment internally if added afterwards (i.e. they don't get added to the DOM element as properties - just speculation though)

Comment: @Pekka: it does work with the title. So it seems like it is specific to events.

Comment: @Senseful ah, good to know. @Galambalazs's approach may be the only way then, although it's expensive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/agace3/2/)]**

```
/**
* Returns all the elements with the specified attribute.
* @param base is optional (root element)
*/
function getElementsByAttr( attr, base ) {
  base = base || document;
  var all = base.getElementsByTagName('*'),
      len = all.length,
      res = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    if ( all[i][attr] != null )
      res.push( all[i] )
  return res;
}
```

*Please note that the function checks all elements in the DOM (if no root element is given) so it can become slow when used on heavy layouts.*

Comment: This does indeed work. I was hoping there would be a jQuery solution.

Comment: while that jQuery does match elements, it won't match the correct ones, since `:has` is looking for any descendants that have that attribute. So for example, it will always match my `<div>` tag's ancestors (e.g. `<body>`) but won't actually match the `<div>` tag itself. I'm just going to use your original code, which seems to work flawlessly. Thanks.

Comment: well I'm not that into jQuery. Should've read more carefully the docs. The original one is still stable.